# R pie() adjust thickness of lines

Tags: r, pie-chart

I tried all sorts of cex options as I found in help, they do not alter  thickness of lines of pie() plot.

```
x <- c(21, 62, 10, 53)
labels <- c("London", "New York", "Singapore", "Mumbai")
pie(x, labels, main = "City pie chart", col = rainbow(length(x)))
#same as:
pie(x, labels, main = "City pie chart", cex.line=100, col = rainbow(length(x)))
```

How can I alter  thickness of lines in pie()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe base `pie()` does not include the `lwd` parameter to be modified.

You can do it by setting it beforehand in the **Graphical Parameters**.

To see the defaults line width:

```
par()$lwd
```

Now to change it you can try:

```
par(lwd = 3)
pie(x, labels, main = "City pie chart", col = rainbow(length(x)))
```

[image]